# Calculating total area of three partially overlapping polygons (without counting area of overlap more than once) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, merge, dissolve

I want to calculate the area of three 1 km buffers without counting the area of overlap more than once. I have used the merge tool to combined the three polygons and then I have used the dissolve tool.

Is this the correct way to calculate the total area of the three polygons without counting the area of overlap more than once?

I wasn't sure if there was another tool which would be better suited to this.

[image]

Comment: Which "merge tool" did you use?  There is one for editing and one for geoprocessing.

Comment: I used the one in the data management toolbox. I'm not sure if that's the editing or geoprocessing one.

Comment: That's the geoprocessing one.  Were the three polygons in separate features classes before using that?

Comment: Yes. Do you know if that was the correct way to do it? I was unsure of whether to use the union tool. Thanks

Comment: What did your result of Merge + Dissolve look like displayed in your inputs?

Comment: It looks right. I've just tried it using the Union tool, which I guess is the only other option of doing this, and I got the same result. So I guess it's correct.